# Regex TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, csv

I am trying to iterate over a column of a pandas series coming from several csv files.
I am iterating because I need to check each row to see if the formatting matches what we want. If it doesn't I want to create a tuple of each failed formatting of the form ("<bad value?", "filename"). I haven't implemented this tuple yet but wanted to get the logic right first:

```
def process_csv_formatting(csv):
    odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None,names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'])
    odfscsv_df['CSV_FILENAME'] = csv.name
    odfscdate_re = re.compile(r"\d{10}")
    #print(odfscsv_df)
    errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'] if not odfscdate_re.search(x)]
    #errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']]

    print(errortup)
    # for index, row in odfscsv_df.iterrows():
    #     print(type(row['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME']))
    return odfscsv_df
```

This function is being called here:

```
def odf_history_from_csv_to_dbtable(db_instance):
odfsdict = db_instance['odfs_tester_history']
#table_row = {}
totalresult_list = []

dir_dict = make_dict_of_csvprocessing_dirs()
#print(dir_dict)
csvbase_path_list = dir_dict["csvbase_path_list"]
archivefiles_path_set = dir_dict["archivefiles_path_set"]
errorfiles_path_set = dir_dict["errorfiles_path_set"]
emptyfiles_path_set = dir_dict["emptyfiles_path_set"]

for csv in csvbase_path_list:  # is there a faster way to compare the list of files in archive and history?
    if csv not in archivefiles_path_set and csv not in errorfiles_path_set and csv not in emptyfiles_path_set:
        csvhistoryfilelist_to_dbtable(csv, db_instance)
        odfscsv_df = process_csv_formatting(csv)
        result = odfscsv_df.to_sql('odfs_tester_history', con=odfsdict['engine'], if_exists='append', index=False)
        totalresult_list.append(result)


    else:
        print(csv.name + " is in archive folder already")
#print (totalresult_list)
return totalresult_list
```

This iterates through my first csv well. I did print the type of data in the column of the first csv and it was , when I do this for the second csv, it shows up as <'class int'>. When I run the function, it succesfully processes the data from the first csv but throws out the following error for the second csv who's "create_datetime" data somehow is of type int:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory3.py", line 234, in 
odf_history_from_csv_to_dbtable(db_instance)
File "C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory3.py", line 214, in odf_history_from_csv_to_dbtable
odfscsv_df = process_csv_formatting(csv)
File "C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory3.py", line 190, in process_csv_formatting
errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'] if not odfscdate_re.search(x)]
File "C:/Users/sys_nsgprobeingestio/Documents/dozie/odfs/odfshistory3.py", line 190, in 
errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'] if not odfscdate_re.search(x)]
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

I thought regex works for ints and strings? How can I get around this issue without modifying the data of the csv dataframe?

Comment: errortup = [x for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'] if not odfscdate_re.search(str(x))]

Comment: Yeah I figured that once I typed it lol. My question is now, how can I make a list of tuples if and only if x doesn't match the regex. I tired: 
errortup = [(odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'],x,csv.name) for x in odfscsv_df['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'] if not odfscdate_re.search(str(x))], but it gives me everything in the file.

Comment: odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'] ==> You select the entire column.  What are you trying today? What info do you want?

Comment: You can use pandas conditional selection. It would be easier.

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen Never heard of pandas conditional selection. What does it do? does it use regex. I figured out what I wanted to do by using the zip command in my list comprehension.

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen WOuld I be able to use the conditional selection with regex. The key here is to capture every date data that doesn't follow a specific format. I don't see how else to do it without regex and a list comprehension

Comment: Create another column. For example, df['ErrorFlag'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 1 if  re.search(r'\d{10}', str(x))  else 0)

Comment: df[ df['ErrorFloag'] == 0]

Comment: Actually, I need a way to flag the code when it runs into a formatting issue. I need to identify the bad csv and move it to a different directory. I have to have a way of capturing the bad csv files. @PramoteKuacharoen

Comment: When use df[ df['ErrorFlag'] == 0], you will get every row that is not format properly.